# Select Query Not retrieving data from tables?

Tags: sql-server-2008, c#-4.0

I have two tables in my database named...Requests and Balance tracker which has no relation....but i want to select data from two tables and binf it two grid...

Requests

```
          EmpID   |EmpRqsts|EmpDescription|ApproverID
           1      |asdfsb  |sadbfsbdf     |1
           2      |asbfd   |sjkfbsd       |1
```

Balance Tracker

```
          EmpId|BalanceAmnt|LastUpdated
         | 1   |5000       |sdfbk
         | 2   |3000       |sjbfsh
```

Employee Table

```
      EmpId|EmpName
       1   |Anil
       2   |Raghu
```

Now Balance tracker has ForeignKey column  of EmployeeTable...What i want is..iwant to select [EmpName ] from EmpTable [EmpRqsts] from [Requests] and [BalanceAmnt][LastUpdated] from [Balance Tracker] and bind it to grid

This is my stored procedure I am using to retrieve the data

```
create procedure SP_GetEmployeeRequests
    (@ApproverName varchar (50))
as
begin
    select 
        EmployeeDetails.Emp_Username, 
        RequestDetails.Request_Amount,
        RequestDetails.Request_description,
        BalanceTracker.Balance_Amount,
        BalanceTracker.LastApproval,
        BalanceTracker.LastUdated
    from 
        EmployeeDetails, RequestDetails, BalanceTracker
    where 
        EmployeeDetails.Emp_ID = RequestDetails.Emp_ID
        and BalanceTracker.Emp_ID = RequestDetails.Emp_ID
        and RequestDetails.Approved_ID = (select Approved_ID 
                                          from ApprovalDetails  
                                          where Approved_By = @ApproverName)
end
```

Everything is fine till here but this query is retrieving only the column names. But not the values of the tables..can any one help me whats wrong in my query..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
    CREATE procedure SP_GetEmployeeRequests
    (
         @ApproverName varchar (50)
    )
    AS
    BEGIN

    SELECT ed.Emp_Username, rd.Request_Amount, rd.Request_description, bt.Balance_Amount, bt.LastApproval, bt.LastUpdated
    FROM EmployeeDetails ed JOIN RequestDetails rd ON ed.Emp_ID = rd.emp_ID 
    JOIN BalanceTracker bt ON bt.Emp_ID = rd.Emp_ID
    JOIN ApprovalDetails ad ON rd.Approved_ID  = ad.Approved_ID
    WHERE ad.Approved_By = @ApproverName 

    END
    GO
```

Comment: same problem its not retrievn the values

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that you are checking "Approved_ID" while your schema has "Approver_ID"

```
create procedure SP_GetEmployeeRequests
    (
     @ApproverName varchar (50)
    )
    as
    begin
        select ed.Emp_Username
             , rd.Request_Amount
             , rd.Request_description
             , bt.Balance_Amount
             , bt.LastApproval
             , bt.LastUdated
          from RequestDetails rd
          join BalanceTracker bt
            on rd.Emp_ID = bt.Emp_ID
          join EmployeeDetails ed
            on rd.Emp_ID = ed.Emp_ID
          join ApprovalDetails ad
            on rd.Approver_ID = ad.Approver_ID
         where ad.Approver_By = @ApproverName)
    end
    go
```

Comment: Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_GetEmployeeRequests2, Line 7
The multi-part identifier "EmployeeDetails.Emp_Username" could not be bound.

Comment: sorry, forgot to substitute some of the table aliases.